# High Memory Usage While using Api Json Parsing in iOS - Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, memory-management, memory-leaks

Iam doing a news app in which i have included many Frameworks like

- CarbonKit Framework(For smooth navigation between tabs)
- NightNight Framework (For Night Mode Reading)
- Alamofire Framework (For Api Requests)

And other frameworks for push notifications(Firebase) and google ads.

The Problem is the high memory usage while parsing json data, I store each set of data(Like news title,url,date,location etc) as object and store  it in array while parsing through a for loop. So after parsing i have an array of objects containing the news details.

The memory comes around 50MB after loading news and will not come down even after navigation to another page. I have also tried commenting the image displaying section, but the result is the same.

Comment: please mention the reason for the negative marking , so that i can rectify it.

Comment: Check if the array variable is getting deallocated. Does  this array needs to be used in any other view controller ? On a broader perspective would you like to store it offline in core data or fetch from the server every time ?

Comment: iam passing the array object to other view controller and displaying the details in that view controller, so the array cannot be deallocated.

I have also implemented offline method storing the whole json result in core data and parse it in offline mode.

Comment: If you are passing around the data to another view controller till the 2 view Controllers get deallocated your array won't be deallocated. My preferred approach would be to download data into core data deallocate the array then use `NSFetchedResultsController` in the both the view Controllers to fetch data from core data. Also it is better to handle syncing in a separate class as an when the core data changes  `NSFetchedResultsController` reflects those changes.

Comment: When `NSFetchedResultsController` in the view controller goes out of scope it would get deallocated. I am just assuming that your app has more than the 2 view controllers you mentioned.

Comment: Please post code.